# When a certain value of a drop down is selected change a different drop down selection

Tags: jquery

I need to check to see if the user selects a certain value in a drop down menu. If that value is selected I need it to change another drop down menu's selection.

Here is the html for the first drop down. If Quarterly is selected I need Quarterly to be selected in the 2nd drop down. If anything else is selected there will be no change.

```
<select id="frequency" name="frequency">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
  <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly (1 Year Minimum, 4 deliveries)</option>
</select>


   <select id="MonthPlan" name="MonthPlan">
      <option selected="selected" value="">Select One</option>
      <option value="3Months">3 Months</option>
      <option value="6Months">6 Months</option>
      <option value="9Months">9 Months</option>
      <option value="12Months">12 Months</option>
      <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly (1 Year Minimum, 4 deliveries)</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#frequency').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'Quarterly'){
        $('#MonthPlan').val('Quarterly');
    }
});
```

Here a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUwtF/) of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/fQZwb/

or just jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var frequency = $('#frequency');
var MonthPlan = $('#MonthPlan');

frequency.bind("change", function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'Quarterly') {
       MonthPlan.find('option[value="Quarterly"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
    } else {
       MonthPlan.find('option[value=""]').attr('selected', 'selected'); 
    } 
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You only asked for matches based on one value (Quarterly), but if in the future you might add additional items which should cause an automatic selection you could avoid hard-coding and use something like this:

```
$('#frequency').change(function() {
    var frequency = this.value;
    $('#MonthPlan option').each(function() {
        if (this.value === frequency) {
            $('#MonthPlan').val(this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Also, I could see you deciding to disable the second drop down if there is a match, in which case you could use this addition:

```
$('#frequency').change(function() {
    var frequency = this.value;
    $('#MonthPlan option').each(function() {
        var monthPlan = $('#MonthPlan');
        monthPlan.removeAttr('disabled');

        if (this.value === frequency) {
            monthPlan.val(this.value);
            monthPlan.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

For reference: [the jsFiddle of this method](http://jsfiddle.net/se6XH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
<select id="frequency" name="frequency" onChange="selectChange()">
```

And in javascript :

```
function selectChange()
{
    if($("#frequencyoption:selected").val() == "Quarterly")
        $("#frequencyoption").val("Quarterly");

}
```

Comment: IMHO, all the events handling should be in the js with the [`$.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) API. This will be easier to maintain

Comment: You should not bind events inline, especially not, when you are already using jQuery, see [unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)